# Unable to write content to csv in single row

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to write a list to csv format in python and facing a unique challenge with specific row which is in the format:

[('c6',
'',
'2021-01-21',
'Pak vs SA: Security  them play and that\u2019s almost like a generation and that\u2019s missed seeing them play.\n\u201cPakistan fans are very proud of their team, like any other nation, but it is when you tour the subcontinent, you realise people here are very passionate about cricket. They go to every match and support their team however they can. Singing, chanting, there\u2019s energy the whole day,\" the Proteas player cherished. 2017 tour with the ICC World XI\nReflecting on the 2017 tour with the ICC World XI, du Plessis said: \u201cI think [the ICC World XI\u2019s tour of Pakistan] was really important in the context of bringing cricket back into Pakistan. There was zero cricket happening in Pakistan at that stage. Read more: Pak vs SA: Pacer Tabish Khan determined after finally being named in national squad\nThe second Test between the two teams will be played at the Pindi Cricket Stadium, Rawalpindi, from February 4, before they travel to Lahore for three T20Is on 11, 13, and 14 February at the Gaddafi Stadium.\nDu Plessis has played seven Tests against Pakistan in which he has scored 246 runs \u2013 including a century \u2013 at an average of 27.33. Two of those seven games were played in the United Arab Emirates, where Pakistan hosted their home cricket from 2010 until 2019, before the complete restoration of international and top-flight cricket in the country. More From Sports:')]

When I try to write it to a csv with following code:

```
out = open('out.csv', 'w')
for row in l:
   out.write( '"' + '","'.join(row) + '"\n' )
   out = open('out.csv', 'w')
```

The output is splitting at exactly "ICC World XI" i.e. text before ICC World XI is in one cell and the rest text is pushed to the next cell in the same row. However, when I reduce the content (randomly) in the original text, the output looks fine. I'm unable to understand the reason behind it. Can anyone please explain. (I'm bit new to python)

Comment: Did you escape the characters correctly? I don't think so. Please try: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html

Comment: Also in the loop you should open file in 'a' append mode else only one line will ever be written in file.